# Mongoose document.updateOne() not working as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c04vU.png)

Hi, I am trying to update my document using document.updateOne() in mongoose but only the balance field, downlines,

```js
 const username = req.params.username;
  try {
    const partner = await Partner.findOne({ username });
    await partner.updateOne({ isApproved: true });
    const ref = await Partner.findOne({ username: partner.referer });
    if (ref) {
      await ref.updateOne(
        {
          $inc: { points: 10 },
          referer: partner.referer,
          $inc: { earnings: 10 },
          $inc: { balance: 10 },
          $push: { downlines: partner.username },
        },
        { new: true }
      );
      const grandRef = await Partner.findOne({ username: ref.referer });
      if (!grandRef) {
        res
          .status(200)
          .json(
            'Partner approval was successfull with a referrer but no grand referrer'
          );
      } else {
        await grandRef.updateOne(
          {
            $inc: { points: 3 },
            grandReferer: ref.referer,
            $inc: { earnings: 3 },
            $inc: { balance: 3 },
            $push: { grandDownlines: partner.username },
          },
          { new: true }
        );
        res
          .status(200)
          .json(
            'Partner approval was successfull with both referrer and grand referrer'
          );
      }
    } else {
      res
        .status(200)
        .json(
          'Partner approval was successfull without a referrer or a grand referrer'
        );
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json('Something went wrong');
    console.log(err);
  }
```

and grand_downlines updates but the earnings and points do not. Please check my snippet in the attached image and help.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I just realized because I am using "$inc" more than one at the same time and if I change the positions, the last "$inc" updates so I used expressions.

```js
 {
            $push: { downlines: partner.username },
            points: ref.points + 10,
            balance: ref.balance + 10,
            earnings: ref.earnings + 10,
          },
          { new: true }
```